# Move an item in a listbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a list box object and it contains some items. I want to move selected item of the list box to the top of the same listbox

Comment: Use an ObservableCollection, move it to the top, and select it

Comment: I tried to remove the selected item from the list and add it into the top..but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Bind your List Box `ItemsSource` to `ICollectionView` instead of directly to an `ObservableCollection` and that will allow you to easily sort, filter or group your underlying collection without making any changes to the collection itself.

Check out this tutorial at wpftutorial.net:

[How to Navigate, Group, Sort and Filter Data in WPF](https://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html)